# Parameterizing the JSON Data file in the VuGen

Tags: json, loadrunner, vugen

Need some help in LoadRunner scripting in REST API. In my requirement, I'm passing the JSON file in the `web_custom_request` LR Function,
Following is the content of the JSON File

```
{"serviceLayerOperationRequest":{
   "contextObjectId": "36045467715",
   "payload":"{\"UserSessionSearchCriteria\":{\"os_st_id\":\"36045467715\",\"LastName\":\"test\",\"FirstName\":\"test\"}}",                
   "operationLabel": "CustomerSearch",
   "serviceOpInvocationId": "1111111",
   "sessionId": "{SessionID}"
}}
```

New Value is fetched from the previous response body and successfully written into the Parameter `SessionID`

Currently, it picks the string {SessionID}.
In the above JSON file, variable sessionId's value is dynamic, so I want to parameterize it from the Parameters. What should be the correct syntax for this?

Comment: Someone asked exactly the same thing about a month ago... I will try to find it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49347798/how-to-parameterize-the-value-in-json-file-loadrunner/49348303#49348303